# Error in UseMethod("type") : no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor" - Sentiment Analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am a total newbie when it comes to R and want to conduct a sentiment analysis for my term paper, relying on the code of my instructor. However, she used another dictionary so I have to adapt my code which is where the trouble starts.

I am trying to create a variable that scores the occurrence of positive terms. When I run the loop however, I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

I have already searched the internet and read that my data could probably be stored in the wrong format. However, both my data sets (`nss2018` is the data I want to conduct the analysis on; `posterms` contains the positive words of the dictionary) are stored as a list which is the same data type my instructor used.

Since I usually don't work with R, I'm a little desperate and can't make any sense of this.

My code for creating the variable:

```
nss2018$posterms <- 0


for (i in 1:nrow(posterms)) {
  occur <- str_count(nss2018$text, posterms$V1[i])
  nss2018$posterms <- nss2018$posterms + occur                  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `string_count`. If the second argument is a factor you get an error. For example:

```
str_count(as.factor(letters), as.factor(c('a', 'b')))
#Error in UseMethod("type") : 
#  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Convert that to `character` and you will be fine:

```
 str_count(as.factor(letters), as.character(as.factor(c('a', 'b'))))
 #[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So in your case:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(posterms)) {
  occur <- str_count(nss2018$text, as.character(posterms$V1[i]))
  nss2018$posterms <- nss2018$posterms + occur                  
}
```